# Как сохранить ротацию в ответе функции генераторе yield при обращении к функции разных данных?

Tags: python, list, dict, yield, next

```
def gen(sp): #создал функцию генератор, на вход принимает не пустой список
    while True:
        for i in range(len(sp)):
            yield sp[i]
a = [1,2,3]
b = [5,6,7]
spisok = a # spisok является ссылкой на объект
g = gen(spisok) # переменная "g" является генератором и передаёт исх.данные в функцию gen
print(next(g)) # next для вывода по одному значению, это важно
*1* # a[0]
print(next(g))
*2* # a[1]
spisok = b # сменил ссылку
print(next(g))
*3* # должно быть 5 (b[0])
spisok = a # сменил ссылку
print(next(g))
*1* # должно быть 3 (a[2])
```

Как сохраняя ротацию обращений к генератору по списку "a", обратиться со списком "b" и т.д. сохраняя ротацию обращений по всем объектам (спискам) передаваемым на вход?

Коллекцию храню в словаре. По ключу хочу передавать значение (список) в генератор (gen). Всё это в цикле. Проверил, что .update() словаря сохраняет объекты и по одному объекту из словаря после его изменений (словаря) генератор работает. Переопределение g = gen(spisok) ломает ротацию ранее сделанных обращений.

Comment: `spisok[:] = b`.

Comment: он хочет сохранять индекс для каждого списка. Вобщем класс надо писать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в питоне все является объектами, в том числе и функции. Можно создавать свойства у функции и использовать их для хранения между вызовами

```
def gen(name, spisok=[]):
    def f():
        while gen.iter[0] < len(gen.iter[1]) - 1:
            gen.iter[0] += 1
            yield gen.iter[1][gen.iter[0]]

    # если первый вызов, создаем список, по которому будет идти цикл
    # когда массив меняется, сюда подставляются другие значения,
    # а текущие возвращаются в словарь на хранение
    if getattr(gen, 'iter', None) is None:
        gen.iter = [
            -1,
            spisok,
            name
        ]
        gen.save = {name: gen.iter}
        return f()
    # дальше просто обмен значениями между словарем и 
    # данными для текущей итерации
    item = gen.save.setdefault(name, [-1, spisok, name])
    gen.save[gen.iter[2]] = gen.iter
    gen.iter = item
    return f()


a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [5, 6, 7, 8]

g = gen('a', [1, 2, 3])  # переменная "g" является генератором и передаёт исх.данные в функцию gen
print(next(g))  # next для вывода по одному значению, это важно
# 1
print(next(g))
# 2
gen('b', [5, 6, 7, 8])  # сменил ссылку
print(next(g))
# 5
gen('a')  # сменил ссылку
print(next(g))
# 3
gen('b')
print(next(g))
# 6
gen('c', [15,16])
print(next(g))
# 15
gen('b')
print(next(g))
# 7
gen('c')
print(next(g))
# 16
```

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую через сохранение информации в функции и проверку по этой информации поступающих значений, т.к. попробовал напрямую вариант, если g = gen(key, collection[key]) #ключ и значение из словаря, то второго значения не выдаёт даже без смены ключа. Возможно я не совсем понял код.
Если возможно, добавьте коментарии. В частности вопрос, я правильно понимаю что вызов функции f происходит в return и в функцию f ничего не передаётся?

Comment: да, в f ничего не передается - она идет циклом по данным внешней функции

Comment: я упростил код, так должно быть понятнее